# How to split multiple rows into multiple columns in excel?

Tags: sql, excel

So I have an excel file filled with 10,000 rows of data that is only on one column.  The problem is it's not in the correct format.  The columns have a pattern of:

```
"name"
"address"
"city"
"state"
"name"
"address"
"city"
"state"
"name"
...
```

but the problem is I need it to be *"name" "address" "city" "state"*.  I was wondering if there is a way to do this in Excel or maybe using a script.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: How are the values stored? Is there a delimiter? Provide more information and clarify what you need (perhaps provide a sample of what it should look like when done).

Answer (score 2):

If your getting the data from sql... Change your query from vertical to horizontal using pivot. Now you don't have to worry about converting it in excel. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116020/sql-server-2008-vertical-data-to-horizontal)

---

@Laurence has a good formula based solution, however,if you need vba because your doing this over and over with new data dumps from sql here is a VBA solution.

Started with this:

[image]

---

Used this Macro:

```
Sub TransposeColA()
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cntr = 1

    For rowNum = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(rowNum, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Set rngA = Range(Cells(rowNum, 1), Cells(rowNum, 1).Offset(3, 0).Address)
            Range("B" & rowNum & ":E" & rowNum).Value = Application.Transpose(rngA)
            rngA.Delete
        Else
            Rows(rowNum).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            rowNum = rowNum - 1
            cntr = cntr + 1
            If cntr = LastRow Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rowNum
End Sub
```

---

And ended up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to manually cross tab data in Excel:

Assume the data is in column A.
Enter the following forumlae:

```
B1: =INT((ROW() - 1 ) * 4)
C1: =INDIRECT("A" & ($B1 + COLUMN() - COLUMN($B1)))
```

Now select `C1` and drag the bottom right corner handle right four cells. You should see the first row of your data displayed

Finally select `B1` to `F1`. Drag the bottom right corner handle down. The further down, the more rows you'll get.