# How to build a query that SELECT rows into columns for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a query in SQL Server that returns a column for each variable of each unique ID? Below is a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

**Table_Exists**

```
ID    |    LOCATION    |    STATUS
__________________________________
001   |     top        |     3
001   |     mid        |     1
001   |     bot        |     4
002   |     top        |     2
002   |     mid        |     2
002   |     bot        |     1
003   |     top        |     1
003   |     mid        |     4
003   |     bot        |     2
```

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying, obviously without success. The code below returns an error message for incorrect syntax around '=':

```
SELECT  
  ID,
  LOCATION = top AS Top,
  LOCATION = mid AS Middle,
  LOCATION = bot AS Bottom
FROM 
  Table_Exists
```

I trying to build:

**Table_Desired**

```
ID | Top | Middle | Bottom 
__________________________
001|  3  |   1    |  4
002|  4  |   2    |  2 
003|  1  |   4    |  2
```

Comment: it's called a [pivot query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)...

Comment: Have a look at the pivot command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116020/sql-server-2008-vertical-data-to-horizontal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use self join (as long as your `LOCATION` is `NOT NULL` and it contains all `top/mid/bot` values):

```
 SELECT t1.ID, t1.Status AS Top, t2.Status AS Middle, t3.Status AS Bottom
 FROM Table_Exists t1
 JOIN Table_Exists t2
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  AND t1.LOCATION = 'top'
  AND t2.Location = 'mid'
 JOIN Table_Exists t3
   ON t1.ID = t3.ID
  AND t1.LOCATION = 'top'
  AND t3.Location = 'bot';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398871)**</kbd>

For more generic solution use `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT
     [ID]
    ,[Top]    = [top] 
    ,[Middle] = [mid]
    ,[Bottom] = [bot]
FROM #Table_Exists t
PIVOT (
   MAX(STATUS) FOR LOCATION IN ([top],[mid],[bot])
) AS Piv
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/399981)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 This was very helpful

Comment: If any values for "Status" are 0/null the entire row for that "ID" will be excluded. 
If Table_Exists is missing data the PIVOT function can be used to return "ID" rows when "Status" is 0/null

Answer (score 2):

Use pivot function like this

```
SELECT
    ID,
    [top] AS [Top],
    [mid] AS Middle,
    [bot] AS Bottom
FROM(SELECT 
    ID, 
    LOCATION,
    STATUS
FROM 
    Table_Exists) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (AVG(STATUS) FOR LOCATION IN ([top],[mid],[bot])) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: I am getting error message "Error converting data type nvarchar to int."

Any thoughts? @Mihai

Comment: Is your Status column a nvarchar? If so then CAST(STATUS, int) AS STATUS will let get the average