# SQL Server 2014 - displaying vertical data in horizontal format

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014

This is my first time to post on stackoverflow. I hope I’m doing it correctly.

I have a SQL Server 2014 table that contains “verticle” data I need to rotate into a single record with multiple columns. bluefeet's answer ([SQL Server 2008 Vertical data to Horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116020/sql-server-2008-vertical-data-to-horizontal)) almost worked me, but not quite. I have temp table “#Columns,” which contains a list of column names that can change based on the data, and table “Transaction,” which contains my data. Here are the contents of the #Columns table:

ColumnName  SeqNum
Time    1
Area    2
Density 3
Ref Index   4
H2SO4   5
pH  6
Urea    7
AN  8
TN  9
Ratio   10
NH3 11
SpGr    12
Cl2 13
Fe  14
Gross   15
Comment 99

Here is the relevant data from the Transaction table:

```
TransactionId   SamplePoint_Id  SP_Chem_Id  EntryDate   Time    Chem_Id Value   Comment
636 18  108 7/19/2017   1219    21  1   NULL<br>
637 18  109 7/19/2017   1219    22  2   NULL<br>
638 18  110 7/19/2017   1219    28  3   NULL<br>
639 18  111 7/19/2017   1219    1   4   NULL<br>
640 18  112 7/19/2017   1219    51  693.51  NULL<br>
641 18  113 7/19/2017   1219    2   -442.68 NULL<br>
642 18  114 7/19/2017   1219    61  168.58  NULL<br>
643 18  115 7/19/2017   1219    52  -0.64   NULL<br>
644 18  116 7/19/2017   1219    4   0.1 NULL<br>
645 18  117 7/19/2017   1219    62  1.009   NULL<br>
646 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1219    54  5   NULL<br>
647 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1219    12  6   NULL<br>
648 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1219    33  7   NULL<br>
649 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1219    70  NULL    8.88889E+12<br>
650 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1219    71  NULL    NULL<br>
651 18  108 7/19/2017   1220    21  2   NULL<br>
652 18  109 7/19/2017   1220    22  3   NULL<br>
653 18  110 7/19/2017   1220    28  4   NULL<br>
654 18  111 7/19/2017   1220    1   5   NULL<br>
655 18  112 7/19/2017   1220    51  1413.51 NULL<br>
656 18  113 7/19/2017   1220    2   -729.68 NULL<br>
657 18  114 7/19/2017   1220    61  404.01  NULL<br>
658 18  115 7/19/2017   1220    52  -0.52   NULL<br>
659 18  116 7/19/2017   1220    4   0.07    NULL<br>
660 18  117 7/19/2017   1220    62  2.018   NULL<br>
661 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1220    12  7   NULL<br>
662 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1220    54  8   NULL<br>
663 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1220    33  9   NULL<br>
664 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1220    70  NULL    12341234<br>
665 18  NULL    7/19/2017   1220    71  NULL    NULL<br>
```

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                    from #Columns
                    group by ColumnName, SeqNum
                    order by SeqNum
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                SELECT 
                c1.ColumnName,
                case when len(t.Comment) > 0 then t.Comment when c1.ColumnName = ''Time'' then t.Time else t.Value end as Value
                FROM [Transaction] t
                join Chemical c on t.Chem_Id = c.ChemicalId    
                join SamplePoint sp on t.SamplePoint_Id = sp.SampleId
                join Source s on sp.Source_Id = s.SourceId         
                join #Columns c1 
                ON c.Abbrev = c1.ColumnName 
                where s.Name = ''' + @SourceName + ''' and t.EntryDate = ''' + @Date + '''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Value)
                for ColumnName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

--print @cols
--print @query
execute sp_executesql @query;
```

And here is my result:

```
Time    Area    Density Ref Index   H2SO4   pH  Urea    AN  TN  Ratio   NH3 SpGr    Cl2 Fe  Gross   Comment<br>
1220    NULL    2   3   4   5   693.51  -729.68 404.01  -0.64   0.1 2.018   8   7   9   8888888888888
```

The problems is that I'm only getting one record back from my query, when what I want is two records - one for Time = 1219 and one for Time = 1220. I know (or think) the problems is the aggregate function MAX, which causes the query to return the record with the “max value.” How do I get both records? I can't get the pivot function to work without the aggregate function. Thanks.

Comment: Exclude time column from PIVOT list, since you wan to pivot all values for each Time record.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I created and populated variable colsWithoutTime, which now contains:

[Area],[Density],[Ref Index],[H2SO4],[pH],[Urea],[AN],[TN],[Ratio],[NH3],[SpGr],[Cl2],[Fe],[Gross],[Comment]

And I used colsWithoutTime in the PIVOT list rather than @cols. And I now get error:

Invalid column name 'Time'.

If I use colsWithoutTime to build the SELECT list in the query, the results in the same list of values, without the Time field:

Area Density Ref Index H2SO4 pH Urea AN TN Ratio NH3 SpGr Cl2 Fe Gross Comment
NULL 2 3 4 5 693.51 -729.68 404.01 -0.64 0.10 2.018 8 7 9 8888888888888

Comment: You sub query (the one with inner joins) does not return time column hence the error. My advice: 1. Create a non dynamic version of your SQL query (with all columns included) and get that working first, only then convert it to dynamic SQL. 2. Re-read [PIVOT][https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) docs again carefully, and pay attention to which columns are being returned by each part of the PIVOT query.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex. You are probably right and I am wrong, but I don’t think my inner query is supposed to return the Time column. It’s supposed to return columns ColumnName and Value and pivot those values into another table containing columns in the variable @cols. It doesn’t produce an error; it returns the pivoted table of data, but it only contains the row with the MAX<Value).
<br>
This query:
<br>
SELECT c1.ColumnName,
case when len(t.Comment) > 0 then t.Comment when c1.ColumnName = 'Time' then t.Time else t.Value end as Value

Comment: returns ColumnName and Value, but the value for Time is plugged into the Value column by the case statement.

I changed my query to have hard-coded column names:

Comment: SELECT [Time], [Area], [Density], [Ref Index], [H2SO4], [pH], [Urea], [AN]], [TN], [Ratio], [NH3], [SpGr], [Cl2], [Fe], [Gross], [Comment]
from 
(
SELECT 
c1.ColumnName,
case when len(t.Comment) > 0 then t.Comment when c1.ColumnName = 'Time' then t.Time else t.Value end as Value
FROM [Transaction] t
join Chemical c on t.Chem_Id = c.ChemicalId    
     join SamplePoint sp on t.SamplePoint_Id = sp.SampleId
     join Source s on sp.Source_Id = s.SourceId         
     join #Columns c1 
     ON c.Abbrev = c1.ColumnName 
     where s.Name = SourceName and t.EntryDate = Date 
) x

Comment: pivot 
    (
     max(Value)
     for ColumnName in ([Time], [Area], [Density], [Ref Index], [H2SO4], [pH], [Urea], [AN]], [TN], [Ratio], [NH3], [SpGr], [Cl2], [Fe], [Gross], [Comment])
) p 

But I still get the exact same result. It’s not an error (and I wasn’t getting an error before), it’s just not the result I want. There are two sets or records – one for time 1220 and one for time 1219 – and I’m only getting one of them. And I think it’s because of the MAX function in the PIVOT function.

Comment: I'm obviously not very good at formatting these comments. It was a lot easier to format them in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: that is why you should update your question rather than post this info in comments.

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to update my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You still have not excluded time from your PIVOTed columns. Note that when I say exclude from PIVOT I don't just mean that you remove them from the `PIVOT ... IN` list but that you also change your inner query to return time column as a **separate** column. That is why I suggested to re-read carefully [MSDN Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) docs to understand how `PIVOT` function works.

Inner query `SELECT` should be changed to this (`Time` is returned as a separate column, and `CASE` has no mention of it):

```
SELECT t.TIME, c1.ColumnName,
    CASE 
        WHEN len(t.Comment) > 0     THEN t.Comment
        ELSE t.Value
    END AS Value
```

`Pivot` part should become this (no `Time` column):

```
pivot ( max(Value) for ColumnName in ([Area], [Density], [Ref Index], [H2SO4], [pH], [Urea], [AN]], [TN], [Ratio], [NH3], [SpGr], [Cl2], [Fe], [Gross], [Comment]) ) p
```

Remove time from your `#Columns` table.

Comment: Oh, you are correct sir. I did read the article you referenced, but I still got it wrong. Thank you!