# how to create SQL query for attendance report

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

[i have this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BSqo.png)

from the above data i want to get the date wise attendance for respective student
[expecting for this kind of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1hBM.png)

can anyone please help what sql query should i use

Comment: You better give sample data in text (table format), unless you want us to key in manually :)

Comment: This might be helpful for you, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116020/sql-server-2008-vertical-data-to-horizontal

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CROSS APPLY. I have an example below but it is hard to test since I don't have access to the data. Hopefully, this will at least get you in the right direction.
try this:

```
SELECT 
ca.name, 
ca.attenance_date, 
CASE WHEN ca.present = 1 THEN 'Present' AS Present, 
CASE WHEN ca.present = 0 THEN 'N/A' AS Not_Present,
FROM Table CROSS APPLY Values (name, attenance_date)) ca
(name, attenance_date);
```